# Get data from mixin Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue component that `requires` a file that is a Vue mixin. The file that is required is part of a vendor package so I cannot modify that file. I need to get the `notifications` prop from the mixin. The end result is that I am going to access the `notifications` object and get the amount of read notifications so that I display this count as a computed property. It seems that using `this.notifications` does not work. How can I do this?

Here is my component:

```
var base = require('notifications/notifications');

Vue.component('spark-notifications', {

    mixins: [base],

});
```

Here is the `notifications` file that was required in the previous component:

```
module.exports = {
    props: ['notifications', 'hasUnreadAnnouncements', 'loadingNotifications'],

    /**
     * The component's data.
     */
    data() {
        return {
            showingNotifications: true,
            showingAnnouncements: false
        }
    },


    methods: {
        /**
         * Show the user notifications.
         */
        showNotifications() {
            this.showingNotifications = true;
            this.showingAnnouncements = false;
        },


        /**
         * Show the product announcements.
         */
        showAnnouncements() {
            this.showingNotifications = false;
            this.showingAnnouncements = true;

            this.updateLastReadAnnouncementsTimestamp();
        },


        /**
         * Update the last read announcements timestamp.
         */
        updateLastReadAnnouncementsTimestamp() {
            this.$http.put('/user/last-read-announcements-at')
                .then(() => {
                    this.$dispatch('updateUser');
                });
        }
    },


    computed: {
        /**
         * Get the active notifications or announcements.
         */
        activeNotifications() {
            if ( ! this.notifications) {
                return [];
            }

            if (this.showingNotifications) {
                return this.notifications.notifications;
            } else {
                return this.notifications.announcements;
            }
        },


        /**
         * Determine if the user has any notifications.
         */
        hasNotifications() {
            return this.notifications && this.notifications.notifications.length > 0;
        },


        /**
         * Determine if the user has any announcements.
         */
        hasAnnouncements() {
            return this.notifications && this.notifications.announcements.length > 0;
        }
    }
};
```

The beginning of the Laravel blade template:

```
<spark-notifications
            :notifications="notifications"
            :has-unread-announcements="hasUnreadAnnouncements"
            :loading-notifications="loadingNotifications"
            inline-template>
```

Here is the method in the `spark.js` which gets the notifications:

```
    data: {
            user: Spark.state.user,
            teams: Spark.state.teams,
            currentTeam: Spark.state.currentTeam,

            loadingNotifications: false,
            notifications: null,

            supportForm: new SparkForm({
                from: '',
                subject: '',
                message: ''
            })
        },    

        getNotifications() {
                this.loadingNotifications = true;

                this.$http.get('/notifications/recent')
                    .then(response => {
                        this.notifications = response.data;

                        this.loadingNotifications = false;
                    });
            },
```

And, here is where everything is bootstrapped together `app.js`:

```
require('spark-bootstrap');
require('./components/bootstrap');

var app = new Vue({
    mixins: [require('spark')]
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.notifications` is the correct way.  If that is not defined, it is because no `notifications` prop was passed to the component.

Edit: The reason it was `null` in the `ready()` function is that the http request retrieving the notifications hadn't returned yet.  OP was trying to get the count of unread notifications, which we got working like so:

```
Vue.component('spark-notifications', { 

    mixins: [base], 

    computed: { 
        notificationCount:function(){ 
            var unread = this.notifications.notifications.filter(function(notif){ 
                return !notif.read; 
            });
            return unread.length 
        }
    } 

});
```

Comment: On the `ready` function, when I `console.log(this.notifications);`, I get `null` in the console. I put the beginning of the blade template in the question so you can see what that looks like.

Comment: and `notifications` is defined somewhere else as well?

Comment: That is correct. Same Vue instance but in a completely different file using an `$http.get` request. The method that gets the notifications is called on the `created` method. Not sure how to get it from there to my Vue file. I can access within my blade file, but I need to do some calculations.

Comment: Well everything seems right so far, and we have a `null` instead of `undefined`, so the problem is further up the chain somewhere and we're passing in a null variable to the component.  can you share some additional code like how `notifications` is retrieved from the server and passed into Vue?

Comment: I added some more code in my question. It's kinda hard because all of the code is separated into modules, which makes for cleaner code, but having to look in a ton of files is a challenge.

Comment: hmmm ok and in the `created()` function you're calling `this.getNotifications()`? When you console log your `$http.get()` response do the notifications exist?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109817/discussion-between-dc-tc-and-jeff).